# Деятельная работа?

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов

Правильно ли будет написать: "деятельная работа"? То есть не получится ли по смыслу "масло масленое"?

Comment: Именно так и получится. Впрочем, может быть в контексте и будет смотреться, но нужен контекст.

Answer (score 2):

Выражение "деятельная работа" применяется в литературе со значением "активный, старательный".

Моё одиночество, впрочем, не одиночество было, а деятельная работа над «Августом». [А. И. Солженицын. Бодался теленок с дубом (1967-1974)]

В течение трех недель...в Краснодонском райкоме шла деятельная работа по пополнению подпольных организаций и партизанских отрядов новыми людьми. [А. А. Фадеев. Молодая гвардия (1943-1951)]

И вот начинается спешная и деятельная работа; охочие птицы устраивают гласные и негласные гнезда и, засевши в них, с прилежностью и азартом приступают к делу обстреливания литературы… [М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Литературное положение (1868)]

ДЕЯТЕЛЬНЫЙ, Проявляющий особенную энергию, старание в выполнении какого-л. дела; постоянно действующий, работающий. Д-ая натура. Д. человек. // Способствующий активной деятельности кого-л. Д-ая любовь

Выражение "деятельная работа" не содержит особой коннотации, **но в ироническом смысле может употребляться,** что определяется по контексту.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, допустимо лишь очень ограниченное применение словосочетания "**деятельная работа"**, когда необходимо придать сказанному особый смысл, например - оттенок иронии.

Во всех остальных случаях, этого сочетания следует избегать. Попробуйте использовать варианты **"активная работа"** или **"продуктивная деятельность"**.

Answer (score 1):

*Деятельная работа* — словосочетание хотя и редкое и, возможно, выходящее из употребления, но имеющее право на жизнь, это синоним энергичной, старательной работы, вовсе не плеоназм.

[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9):

> ДЕЯТЕЛЬНЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -лен, -льна, -льно. Проявляющий особенную энергию, старание в выполнении какого-л. дела; постоянно действующий, работающий. Д-ая натура. Д. человек. // Способствующий активной деятельности кого-л. Д-ая любовь. <Деятельно, нареч. Д. принимать участие в чём-л.

В Нацкорпусе нашлось 36 вхождений, и без всякого оттенка иронии. Примеры:

«Подстегнуть» министров **к деятельной работе** в канун двойных выборов. [Александр Садчиков. Вотум-2: перезагрузка (2003) // «Известия», 2003.03.03]

Участие **в деятельной работе** по сохранению памятников истории и искусства может кому-то показаться частностью, а кое-кому и попыткой уйти от действительности в романтизацию прошлого. [С. Петров, Чингиз Айтматов. Возвышение личности (1987) // «Труд», 1987.11.07]